# Angular13: Patch json model into reactive formgroup with nested objects and formArrays in nested components

Tags: json, angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, formgroups

I get json data from a backend which is converted to my model classes (it has nested classes and arrays). Now I want to create a reactive FormGroup by initializing it with my model class. Unfortunately this results in a FormGroup that uses a FormControl and not a FormArray for the arrays of the model class.

If I create the FormGroup manually (at least for the first class) and create a FormArray for the arrays, it is overwritten with the FormControl again if I patch my root model class into the FormGroup.

But I need the FormArray since I want to use nested Components in order to display the data of the model class and edit it. Or my approach is wrong. Either way maybe someone knows a solution to my problem.

Here is my example code (I simplified it with this simple Order model)

```
//MODEL
export class CustomerHistory {
  id?:number;
  orders:Order[];

  public constructor() {
    this.id = undefined;
    this.orders = []
  }
}

export class Order {
  id?:number;
  orderItems:OrderItem[];

  public constructor() {
    this.id = undefined;
    this.orderItems = []
  }
}

export class OrderItem {
  id?:number;
  itemName:string;

  public constructor() {
    this.id = undefined;
    this.itemName = undefined;
  }
}

//AppComponent
initFormGroup() {
    //Either init with Class, but then no FormArrays are created for the arrays
    this.myCustomerHistoryFormGroup = this.fb.group(new CustomerHistory());

    //Or init manually but doesn't go deep enough and is also overwritten by patch
    this.myCustomerHistoryFormGroup = this.fb.group({
      id: "",
      orders: this.fb.array([])
    })
}

//Patching fills all the data of customerHistory into the FormGroup, but also overwrites the FormArray
//of the manually created FormGroup to a FormControl
patchFormGroup(customerHistory: CustomerHistory) {
    this.myCustomerHistoryFormGroup.patchValue(customerHistory);
}

//AppTemplate
<form [formGroup]="myCustomerHistoryFormGroup">
 <div formArrayName='orders'>
  <div *ngFor="let order of myCustomerHistoryFormGroup.get('orders'); let i=index">
    <app-order [formGroup]="order"></app-order>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Best I could do so far is to create and initialize the FormArrays manually which is quite tedious: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-patch-value-deeply-nested-component-utk3qv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Check your template code, too many syntax errors.

```
<form [formGroup]="myCustomerHistoryFormGroup">
    <div formArrayName='orders'>
      <div *ngFor="let order of myCustomerHistoryFormGroup.get('orders')); let i=index">
        <app-order [formGroup]="order"></app-order>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Fixed it thanks. Pasted my component methods directly into the template for the example. Probably not the best idea.

Comment: But official doc how to make dynamic forms didn't help you?

Comment: Unfortunately it shows only things I already know. Not how to just patch a complete Object into a FormGroup with FormArrays. If I manage the FormArrays manually everyhting works already as expected with dynamic created components with the right data.

Answer (score 0):

When we manange a FormGroup with FormArrays it's always the same

1. Create functions that return the formArrays. If is a form array
   inside a formArray your function need the index

   ```
   cvForm: FormGroup;
   get lines()
   {
      return this.cvForm.get('lines') as FormArray;
   }
   players(index:number)
   {
      return this.lines.at(index).get('players') as FormArray;
   }
   ```
2. Create functions that return a FormGroup empty or with data

   ```
   setPlayer(data:any=null)
   {
       data=data || {first_name:'',last_name:''}
       return new FormGroup({
          firstName:new FormControl(data.first_name),
          lastName:new FormControl(data.last_name),
       })
   }
   setLine(data:any=null)
   {
      data=data || {name:'',players:[]}
      return new FormGroup({
        name:new FormControl(data.name),
        players:new FormArray(data.players.map((x:any)=>this.setPlayer(x)))
      })
   }

   setForm(data:any=null)
   {
      data=data || {team_name:'',lines:[]}
      return new FormGroup({
         team_name:new FormControl(data.team_name),
         lines:new FormArray(data.lines.map((x:any)=>this.setLine(x)))
      })
   }
   ```

The advantage of this is that it's easy add/remove a player/lines and create a form with the data or empty

```
this.cfForm=this.setForm() //create an empty FormGroup
this.cvFrom=this.setForm(seedData) //create a formGroup with the data
this.lines.push(this.setLine()) //add an empty line 

//add to the first line of the array a new player
players(0).push(this.setPlayer({
            first_name:'first Name',
            last_name:'last name'}) 
etc.
```

your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-patch-value-deeply-nested-component-fsnsfs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: So this means basically I have to manage the FormArrays by myself and there is no way the FormArrays get automatically created by the FormBuilder when it encounters an array in a model class?!